# Automating Adobe Premiere Pro for trimming videos based on volume level

Tags: premiere, workflow, automation

Good evening,

I have been recording screen-captured videos from my iPad explaining Math concepts (it's a Khan Academy style personal project). After I record it, I trim out the parts in which I'm in silence, either because I am making a diagram, or because I am thinking about what I will say.

I have a question related to automating Adobe Premiere Pro: can I automatically trim out those parts? Is there a solution out there that addresses that? Is it possible to build some code in the software where it trims out "anything below volume X"?

Thank you

Comment: Probably possible, but you'd need to write a script for it. If you're good with Javascript have a look at https://buildmedia.readthedocs.org/media/pdf/premiere-scripting-guide/latest/premiere-scripting-guide.pdf

Answer (score 0):

Try the Auto Gate setting in the Dynamics audio effect. 
It will gate (turn off the audio) if the threshold of the audio falls below a specified level for a specified amount of time. 
Doing this manually would sound better but take longer. 
The gate won’t be able to tell the difference between a deliberate piece of speech and a mouth pop or click, so you may hear the gate open and close when you don’t want it to.

https://helpx.adobe.com/in/premiere-pro/using/audio-effects-transitions.html

Note:It will not trim your clips, just affect whether you hear parts of them in your edit.